# Set initial value of variable by a value from table-C#

Tags: c#

Silly question:
I have  a table like :

```
uid     tid
12312   988834
12341   225653
15428   900972
```

I want to set my variable by the value from first row of tid column.

I tried these commands but they did not work:

```
1 - string x=Convert.ToString(row[tid]);
2 - int x= dt.rows[0]["tid"] ; //dt is the name of my table
```

Comment: The first form should work provided that row is a DataRow extracted from your datatable and tid is not null. The second form need a conversion to int32. Can you explain what doesn't work?

Comment: Could you provide us with a bit more code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
string x=Convert.ToString(row[tid]);
```

Should probably be this assuming you aren't in a loop already.

```
foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    string x = row["tid"].ToString();
}
```

If you are only interested in the *first row*, then you could do this:

```
DataRow row = dt.Rows[0];
string x = row["tid"].ToString();
```

The second line ought to be something like this:

```
int x = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0]["tid"]);
```

Comment: Why are you creating a new string named `x` for every iteration?

Comment: @MaxMommersteeg I'm simply demonstrating that you need a datarow variable, `row` in this case if you intend to use a line like: `row["tid"]`. I assumed that the OP is using a loop to access datarows in this way as is common, though you could do: `DataRow row = dt.Rows[0];` I suppose. And does it really matter anyway? I can think of plenty of examples where you might want `x` to be overwritten, it depends entirely on the code that follows the definition.

Comment: I would in this case just create a `List<string>`, like: `var tidValues = new List<string>(); foreach(var row in dt.Rows){ tidValues.Add(row["tid"].ToString(); }`. All values are still in memory(list) now. Since the real question is:  "want to set my variable by the value from first row of tid column."

Comment: `Since the real question is: "want to set my variable by the value from first row of tid column."` - In which case, iterating over the whole `Rows` collection is unnecessary. I've provided solutions for both scenarios.